# Horário servidor Linux Ubuntu atrasado

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Tenho um servidor Linux rodando Ubuntu 14.4, configurado com o `timezone America/Sao_Paulo`.

Mas o horário que ele esta pegando esta 2 min atrasado, parece pouca coisa, mas como o sistema que roda nele precisa habilitar funcionalidades em determinados horário exatos, o usuário acaba achando que é um erro.

Usando o comando `date` ele me exibe o seguinte horário

> **$ date**
>
> Wed Feb  3 17:00:18 BRST 2016

Porém agora é `17:02`

Comment: Provavelmente não tem NTP (sincronismo de data/hora) ativo na máquina. Se for VM, pode ter que configurar a sincronização no sistema de virtualização (instalar o cliente da VM no OS pode ser um caminho).

Comment: Muito obrigado @Bacco, funcionou perfeitamente, se puder colocar isso como resposta para eu selecionar e ajudar outras pessoas futuramente :) - Usei esse [tutorial](http://blogging.dragon.org.uk/setting-up-ntp-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: Jeferson, se puder postar de maneira resumida como foi que solucionou, como resposta sua, sera de grande valia para outros com o mesmo problema. Eu até poderia tentar pesquisar e elaborar algo específico para Ubuntu, mas como você está com "a mão na massa", acho que conseguiria elaborar mais rápido que eu. Se forem máquinas no Brasil, recomendo usar os servidores `a.ntp.br`, `b.ntp.br` e `c.ntp.br`, por causa do tempo de resposta menor que os do exterior.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o meu problema com a ajuda do @Bacco instalando o NTP no servidor.

**1º Instalar o NTL**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ntp ntpdate
```

**2º Alterar as configurações no arquivo `ntp.conf`**

```
sudo nano /etc/ntp.conf
```

**3º Alterar os servidor padrão pelos servidor de sua escolha**

Altere essa parte que esta nas configurações

```
server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
# Use Ubuntu's ntp server as a fallback.
server ntp.ubuntu.com
```

Por

```
server 0.br.pool.ntp.org
server 1.br.pool.ntp.org
server 2.br.pool.ntp.org
server 3.br.pool.ntp.org
```

(Caso queira utilizar o servidor brasileiro - [lista completa de servidores](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/@))

**4º Depois de 10 - 20 minutos que fez os passos acima, o NTP irá sincronizar os horários.**

Pode executar o código abaixo para visualizar informações de delay entre os servidores e outras informações

**5º Pare e inicie o serviço do NTP**

```
sudo service ntp start
sudo service ntp stop
sudo service ntp restart
```

---

Utilizei [este tutorial](http://blogging.dragon.org.uk/setting-up-ntp-on-ubuntu-14-04/) para resolver o problema, seguindo a dica do @Bacco